# Alfresco Share: does it have document content search like Sharepoint?

Tags: alfresco

When I upload document to *Alfresco Share* site I can add some tags to search document later. However tags are not reliable - tags depend on person who adds them.

I wonder if *Alfresco Share* has ability for document context search as a plugin, google search or some of a kind? I'd like to make my documents (pdf, winword) searchable by words inside document, not by tags.

Answer (score 7):

Most of the text files (txt, xml, html, doc, pdf, ...) are already parsed and indexed by Alfresco as an out of the box feature, meaning that full-text search is already enabled. You don't need to perform any extra action. Just create a site, upload a PDF into its document library and try to search using one word used within the PDF content.

Besides, the whole indexing and search process is performed by the Alfresco Repository, Alfresco Share is just a UI application that allows you to better leverage the content you store into the repository.

Comment: note however, that the documents (especially PDF) need to actually contain Text. If the PDF is "just" a scanned Image, it wont contain any text, and so will not be searchable (only searchable by metadata)